# modifing xpath to find necessary element in it

Tags: xpath

Can you advise me, please, is there any way to modify the following xpath so that the only picture name us.gif can be found.

```
//img[contains(@src,
               'http://cache.global.com/cache/1102A/images/flags/icon/us.gif')]
```

Comment: seriously? just take out everything in the url except the us.gif. Or is your question that you want to return only the filename of the img element.

Comment: Firstly, I suspect you want "=" rather than contains() - that is, you want this string to be the whole attribute value, not just part of it. Apart from that, sorry, your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether an attribute holds exactly one constant value, you can do it this way:

```
//img[@src='us.gif']
```